# WPF : My window is showing inside another big one, only in execution

Tags: wpf

I created a small "ProgressWindow" with progressbar. In xaml editor, it's ok, no problem.
But when I created window and show it in my codebehind, the ProgressWindow is displaying inside another big white window ... What is that ?

In xaml editor :
[image]

In execution :
[image]

Xaml Code :

```
<Window x:Class="MyStyling.Control.ProgressWindow"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyStyling.Control" WindowStyle="none" ResizeMode="NoResize">

<Border  x:Name="Xaml_ProgressWindow_ID" Width="320" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrushKey}}" Background="{DynamicResource MyBackgroundBrush}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="0,0,0,20">
    <Border.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect Color="Gray" 
                          Direction="300"
                          BlurRadius="10"
                          Opacity="0.5"
                          ShadowDepth="10" />
    </Border.Effect>

    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="XAML_SP_ProgressBar1_ID">
            <Label x:Name="XAML_LBL_ProgressBar1_ID" Content="Main progress bar ..." HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            <ProgressBar x:Name="XAML_PG_ProgressBar1_ID" Height="5" Margin="20,0,19,0" Background="White" Foreground="Black" />
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel x:Name="XAML_SP_ProgressBar2_ID" Margin="0,10,0,0">
            <Label x:Name="XAML_LBL_ProgressBar2_ID" Content="Secondary progress bar" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="11" />
            <ProgressBar x:Name="XAML_PG_ProgressBar2_ID" Height="5" Margin="20,0,19,0" Background="White" Foreground="Black" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `SizeToContent` property of the window to `WidthAndHeight` to automatically size the window to fit the `Border`:

```
<Window x:Class="MyStyling.Control.ProgressWindow"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyStyling.Control" WindowStyle="none" ResizeMode="NoResize"
     SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
```

Or wrap the `Border` in a `ViewBox` to strecth it to the size of the window:

```
<Window x:Class="MyStyling.Control.ProgressWindow"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyStyling.Control" WindowStyle="none" ResizeMode="NoResize"
     Height="200" Width="320">
    <ViewBox>
        <Border x:Name="Xaml_ProgressWindow_ID" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrushKey}}" Background="{DynamicResource MyBackgroundBrush}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="0,0,0,20">
            ...
        </Border>
    </ViewBox>
</Window>
```